# How to serve files for download? Trying to serve files for users to view/download, but server responds with wrong Content-Type

Tags: apache, http, browser, http-headers, webserver

I have a functionality on a website in which the user logs in and then a list of files available for download is showed. When he clicks on the file, it should show a download dialog with the options for open with the application if one is installed for the filetype (like Acrobat Reader if it is installed, for example) or prompt download if it's not. Currently, I'm building the list using PHP just echoing each file's path. Then, when the user clicks on the link, the browser directly requests the file. My first problem with this was that ppsx or pptx files were displayed in the browser as plain text files, resulting on garbage-on-screen. Then I added an .htaccess file on the directory where the files to be served are, with this content:

```
Options All -Indexes

Header set Content-Disposition attachment
```

With that .htaccess file, the browser dialog appears but, for example, in Firefox, it has the option "Open with: Notepad", instead of the correct application for the file or none if there isn't an application installed for the filetype. I can see that the response header Content-Type is "text/plain" and that's wrong, but how can I make the correct Content-Type be detected by the server?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct [MIME Content-Type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/) to get the appropriate response from the browser for a specific file type.

Powerpoint is:

```
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
```

You can modify your .htaccess file for the updated MIME types as shown on [this site](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/mime-types-htaccess.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Sounds like it goes near this way, but the thing is i don't know what filetypes they want to upload. It could be PPSX, PDF, DOCX, TXT, ZIP, etc.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with Apache, but the browser will use the file type when given a generic MIME type such as application/octet-stream

But you can also configure the server for the common file types you'll encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I gave up and rewrited how it works. In my views, I print the path to a controller method and pass a parameter to it with the file id. The controller checks the user id with the session, looks for the file in the database and then there is this code:

```
if (file_exists($file['path'])) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file['name']);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file['path']));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file['path']);
    exit;
}
```

It successfuly makes the browser to popup a download dialog also giving the option to open it with the associated application if it's installed.